# Postgres group by quarter

Tags: postgresql

I have table with columns: topic, person, published_date. I would like to create query which help me compute how many times every person wrote in specific topic in every quarter. Example:

```
topic person published_date

'world'  JS   2016-05-05 
'world'  JS   2016-05-10
'nature'  AR   2016-12-01
```

should return something like

```
topic person quarter how_many_times
'world'  JS     2          2
'nature' AR     4          1
```

I'm able to group it by topic and person

```
select topic, person, published_date, count(*) from table group by topic, person, published_date
```

but how group published_date into quarters?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Assuming that the `published_date` is a date type column you can use the `extract` function like this:

```
select 
  topic, 
  person,
  extract(quarter from published_date) as quarter, 
  count(*)
from 
  table1
group by 
  topic, 
  person,
  extract(quarter from published_date)
order by 
  extract(quarter from published_date) asc
```

[Sample SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!15/9204b/4)

If the dates can fall into different years you might want to add the year to the select and group by.

Comment: Wow, amazing, thank you a lot! +1 for sample sql fiddle

Comment: Do you need to use re-declare "extract(quarter from published_date)" again in the group by or order by statement? I.e. define `quarter` it in the select clause only. Because If I use the alias "quarter" in both the group by and order by clauses, my query still works.

Comment: @Learner It might be that it has changed in more recent versions, but I believe that at the time I wrote the answer it would have been necessary to do it that way to adhere to the standard, but I could be wrong. It probably comes down to how the database engine used parses the query and resolves aliases, i.e. if it's done in a single och multi pass fashion. That would be my guess anyway.

Answer (score 10):

If you want both quarter and year you can use [date_trunc](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-datetime.html#FUNCTIONS-DATETIME-TRUNC):

```sql
SELECT
  date_trunc('quarter', published_date) AS quarter
```

This gives the date rounded to the start of the quarter, e.g. `2020-04-01`, and has the advantage that subsequent steps in the pipeline can read it like a normal date.

(This compares to [extract](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-datetime.html#FUNCTIONS-DATETIME-EXTRACT) (`extract(quarter FROM published_date)`), which gives the number of the quarter, i.e. 1, 2, 3, or 4.)

Comment: Agree this is useful. As the date isn't lost, just truncate to the quarter start date. Useful if your data spans multiple years.

Answer (score 4):

If someone also needs the year, they can use this:

```
SELECT (extract(year from published_date)::text || '.Q' || extract(quarter from published_date)::text) as quarter
```

This will return the value in the form `2018.Q1`.

How does it work? It extracts both year and quarter (which are both of type `double precision`), casts them into strings, and concatenates the whole in something readable.

Comment: This is really cumbersome. Why not simply `to_char(published_date, 'YYYY."Q"Q')`?